# Is Overriding virtual methods with template methods in derived class possible?

Tags: c++11

I want to override virtual methods from base class with template methods in derived class; Just want to know if there is any smart way or work around to make this possible.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    virtual void AF(int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Function in A" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void af(int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Function in A" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B
{
    virtual void BF(int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Function in B" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void bf(int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Function in B" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<bool IS_A>
struct C : public A, public B
{
    template<class I>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, I>::value && IS_A,void>::type AF(I i)
    {
        std::cout << "Function override from A in C" << std::endl;
    }
    template<class I>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, I>::value && !IS_A,void>::type BF(I i)
    {
        std::cout << "Function override from B in C" << std::endl;
    }
    template<class I>
    void af(I i)
    {
        std::cout << "Function override from A in C" << std::endl;
    }
    template<class I>
    void bf(I i)
    {
        std::cout << "Function override from B in C" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    int i(0);
    {
        A * a = new C<true>();
        a->AF(i);
        a->af(i);
    }
    {
        B * b = new C<false>();
        b->BF(i);
        b->bf(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

- Function in A //Want this to be Function override from A in C
- Function in A //Want this to be Function override from A in C
- Function in B //Want this to be Function override from B in C
- Function in B //Want this to be Function override from B in C

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of using template for C::AF and C::BF if you only enable them for the same `int` of A's and B's?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CRTP idiom to do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<type_traits>

struct A
{
    virtual void AF(int)
    {
        std::cout << "Function in A" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void af(int)
    {
        std::cout << "Function in A" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B
{
    virtual void BF(int)
    {
        std::cout << "Function in B" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void bf(int)
    {
        std::cout << "Function in B" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename D>
struct CRTP: public A, public B
{
    template<typename I> void CAF(I i) { A::AF(i); }
    template<typename I> void af(I i) { A::af(i); }
    template<typename I> void CBF(I i) { B::BF(i); }
    template<typename I> void cbf(I i) { B::bf(i); }

    void AF(int i) override { static_cast<D*>(this)->CAF(i); }
    void af(int i) override { static_cast<D*>(this)->caf(i); }
    void BF(int i) override { static_cast<D*>(this)->CBF(i); }
    void bf(int i) override { static_cast<D*>(this)->cbf(i); }
};

template<bool IS_A>
struct C : CRTP<C<IS_A>>
{
    template<class I>
    void CAF(I i)
    {
        std::cout << "Function override from A in C" << std::endl;
    }
    template<class I>
    void CBF(I i)
    {
        std::cout << "Function override from B in C" << std::endl;
    }
    template<class I>
    void caf(I i)
    {
        std::cout << "Function override from A in C" << std::endl;
    }
    template<class I>
    void cbf(I i)
    {
        std::cout << "Function override from B in C" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int i(0);
    {
        A * a = new C<true>();
        a->AF(i);
        a->af(i);
    }
    {
        B * b = new C<false>();
        b->BF(i);
        b->bf(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a difference: if one of the 4 functions is not overrided in C, this is not the one in A or B which is called, this is CRTP's and you have an infinite recursion!

Comment: @O'Neil Updated. No more infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

First, to "enable/disable" member functions according to `IS_A`, you can just define both `true` and `false` specializations of C:

```
template <bool IS_A>
struct C;

template <>
struct C<true> : A, B
{
    // functions only defined for IS_A == true
};

template <>
struct C<false> : A, B
{
    // functions only defined for IS_A == false
}
```

And to introduce the overriding by the template's, you can override the ones from A and B where you call the template ones:

```
void af(int i) override { af<int>(i); }
void bf(int i) override { bf<int>(i); }
```